# p calendar readonly not working in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-bootstrap-calendar

<p-calendar readonly="true" [showTime]="true" inputId="time" [hourFormat]="24" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="tomorrow" inputId="range" [(ngModel)]="obj.date" formControlName="selectedDateTime">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Readonly** property doesn't exist in **p-calendar**. You can use the "**disabled**" property instead.

```
    <p-calendar 
    disabled="true" 
    [showTime]="true" 
    inputId="time" 
    [hourFormat]="24" 
    [minDate]="minDate" 
    [maxDate]="tomorrow" 
    inputId="range" 
    [(ngModel)]="obj.date" 
    formControlName="selectedDateTime"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **[readonlyInput]="true"** instead of **readonly="true"**

Note - readonlyInput when specified, prevents entering the date manually with keyboard. Default value is null

Reference - https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

I think when readonlyInput is true must be showOnFocus false
Please see link https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10880